# Merge 2 columns into one in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

This should be simple, but I am struggling with it.

I want to combine two columns in a single dataframe into one.  I have separate columns for custemer ID (20227) and year (2009).  I want to create a new column that has both (2009_20227).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some alternative way with function `unite` in `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
df = data.frame(year=2009:2013, customerID=20227:20231) # using akrun's data

unite(df, newcol, c(year, customerID), remove=FALSE)

#      newcol year customerID
#1 2009_20227 2009      20227
#2 2010_20228 2010      20228
#3 2011_20229 2011      20229
#4 2012_20230 2012      20230
#5 2013_20231 2013      20231
```

Comment: can add multiple columns (more than two) in c(), or you can just do column index like unite(df, newcol, 1:2, remove=FALSE, sep="_").

Comment: what if newcol is a character variable? Also, can it merge columns from two different dataframes?

Answer (score 24):

You could use `paste`

```
transform(dat, newcol=paste(year, customerID, sep="_"))
```

Or use `interaction`

```
dat$newcol <- as.character(interaction(dat,sep="_"))
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(year=2009:2013, customerID=20227:20231)
```

Comment: interaction is very interesting! R is full of good surprises!

Comment: Yes, but it returns a `factor` class

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative (using the example of @akrun):

```
dat <- data.frame(year=2009:2013, customerID=20227:20231)
dat$newcol <- paste(dat$year, dat$customerID, sep="_")
```